# consequence of existence of square roots of elements of quotient groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm stuck with the following (from C. Pinter's *A Book of Abstract Algebra*, 2nd ed., p. 153 ex. C 4.)

Let $G$ be a group and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$. Suppose that every element of the quotient group $G/N$ has a square root. Prove that for every $x \in G$ there exists $y \in G$ such that $xy^2 \in N$.

Use the fact that $Na = N \Leftrightarrow a \in N$, where $a \in G$ and $Na$ is the right coset of $N$ by $a$.

My first attempt was as follows:

Let $Nx$ (where $x \in G$) be any coset of $N$ (i.e., a member of $G/N$). By hypothesis it has a square root, therefore there exists $y \in G$ such that $Nx = (Ny)^2$. By the definition of coset multiplication, this means $Nx = Ny^2$, hence $(Nx)^{-1} Ny^2 = N$, since $N$ is the identity of $G/N$. This means $N(x^{-1}y^2) = N$, and by the abovementioned result, $x^{-1}y^2 \in N$.

But what I'm trying to prove is $xy^2 \in N$, not $x^{-1}y^2 \in N$... And I don't see any reason to think that $x^{-1}y^2 \in N \Rightarrow xy^2 \in N$.

The (partial) solution is the book confirms that the first few steps are right, but then obviously I'm getting something wrong. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have shown that for arbitrary $x\in G$, there is some $y$ such that $x^{-1}y^2 \in N$.  As $x$ ranges over all elements of $G$, so does $x^{-1}$, so this is enough.

Alternatively:  start with $Nx^{-1}$ instead of $Nx$.

Comment: Oh, of course! Thank you very much. I'm embarrassed not to have seen that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, using @universalset's answer, here is a complete solution.

Let $x \in G$. $G$ being a group, $x$ has an inverse, $x^{-1}$, in $G$, and the coset $N(x^{-1})$ is a member of the quotient group $G/N$. By hypothesis, $N(x^{-1})$ has a square root, that is, there exists $y \in G$ such that $N(x^{-1}) = (Ny)^2$. Multiplying on the left by $Nx$, we obtain $N = Nx (Ny)^2$, i.e., $N(xy^2) = N$, from which we conclude that $xy^2 \in N$, as desired.

Now, suppose that for any $x \in G$ there is a $y \in G$ such that $xy^2 \in N$. Let $Na$ be any element of $G/N$, where $a \in G$. Then $a^{-1} \in G$, and by hypothesis, there exists $b \in G$ such that $a^{-1}b^2 \in N$. Then $N = N(a^{-1}b^2) = N(a^{-1})Nb^2 \Rightarrow Na = (Nb)^2$, in other words, $Na$ has a square root.